# Problem with Ilford Multigrade RC?

Tags: film, darkroom, paper, developer, ilford

Is anyone else having a problem with new boxes of Ilford Muligrade RC? Even when exposing the paper to white light for an absurd amount of time, it is only going light gray in the developer. I am using fresh developer at the correct temperature, and I repeated the test on an older box of Ilford multigrade warmtone, and didn’t have any problems (the paper goes black almost immediately). All of the new paper I bought has this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, did you do the tests side by side in the same setting? It might be that something changed from your initial test with new paper to your second test with old paper

Comment: I'd contact the official Ilford distributor in your area. If this is indeed a widespread problem, they're probably aware if it by now. If it's a limited bad batch, all of it might have wound up in the same distribution channel and thus in the same world area/country.